# How can i blank a child dropdown when parent down has been changed in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

The data is coming from backend, whats happening now is, say parent dropdown have P1,P2,P3 and corresponding childs are C11,C12 for P1; C21,C22 for P2; C31, C32 for P3.
When P1 is selected, child dropdown will show C11,C12, but when P2 is selected, child dropdown should go blank. In my case list is showing fine, i.e., C21 and C22. But when selected P2 after P1, child dropdown is not going blank.

```
<Select
      label=""
      defaultText="All"
      onSelection={handleParentSelection}
      itemList={[...ParentList]}
      onChange={handleParentChange}
/>
<Select
      label=""
      defaultText="All"
      onSelection={handleChildSelection}
      itemList={[...ChildList]}
      onChange={handleChildChange}
/>
```

Comment: can you share more code? is Select a third party component you used?

Comment: Yes, select is actually from a specified library.